# Using Gitlab rules to exclude a certain job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I want to exclude some jobs from Gitlab pipeline if there's a merge request (MR) with a specific source & target branch (or a merge request with a a specific title). I have 3 branches: development, testing and production. The logic is following:

- If there's a MR from production branch into testing branch (MR title = "production into testing"), my job shouldn't run;
- If there's a MR from testing branch into development branch (MR title = "testing into development"), my shouldn't run either;
- If there's any other MR that's not listed above (MR name doesn't matter, but it can't be one of the two above), my job should run.

I tried different combinations of rules, but none of them seem to work. Here are some examples of how I tried this to accomplish:

```
rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "production" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "testing"
     when: never
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "testing" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "development"
     when: never
   - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```

Here I tried to combine the first two rules from previous example and excluded specific MR titles:

```
rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "production" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "testing" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "testing" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "development"
     when: never
   - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE != "production into testing"
   - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE != "testing into development"
```

And here's the last example what I wanted to show:

```
rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE == "production into testing" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE == "testing into development"
     when: never
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "production" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "testing" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"
```

None of this examples are working. [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules) states that rules are validated one by one until the first match. When there's a match, the rule is executed. No further rules should be considered. My usual workflow is that there is some feature branch that is merged into all three branches: development, testing, and production. At this point, every job for each pipeline is running because source & target branch or MR title doesn't match one of those never-run-type rules above. When there's a merge into production, there's a job, that using API automatically, creates two new merge requests (only creates) - from "production into testing" and from "testing into development". This is where the problem starts. When I do the merge, the job with all those never-run-type rules are still executed in the testing or development pipeline despite the fact that the MR title or source & target branches in the rule prevents this particular job from executing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you found the documentation about [Merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html). You need to enable them, of the 1st view your rules doing that already

Comment: Can you share a screenshot form the pipeline view 
`https://gitlab.com/{ ORG }/{ Group }/{ Project }/-/pipelines/{ PipelineID }`
for the different rules and triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to SO.

Can you try that here? So combine the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` with the source branch name and target branch name rule together as a single statement?

I would avoid "MR title parsing" and would not use it in a title.

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
          && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "production"
          && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "testing"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
          && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "testing"
          && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "development"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: on_success
```

You can also echo the variables in "always" running job. So you get some debug infos and can check your rules.

```yaml
debug:
  script:
    - echo ${CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE}
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
  rules:
    - when: always
```

You wrote that the Pipelines are triggered over the API, so may the $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE is "api" and not "merge_request_event".

See here [Predefined CI/CD variables reference: `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

> How the pipeline was triggered. Can be push, web, schedule, api, external, chat, webide, merge_request_event, external_pull_request_event, parent_pipeline, trigger, or pipeline. For a description of each value, see Common if clauses for rules, which uses this variable to control when jobs run.